# Trying to Repeat, but data is not a multiple

Tags: r, repeat, datamatrix

So I am trying to label a data matrix with conditions; however, when I did my experiment, I had 3 tubes where I repeated the first two 7 times and the third tube 6 times.  How can I code the matrix to be re-written and ignore that there is "missing" data:

```
dm$Strain<-dm$variable
dm$Strain<-rep(c("446-1", "446-2", "446-3"), each.out=193)
dm$Strain<-factor(dm$Strain)
levels(dm$Strain)

Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "Strain", value = c("446-1", "446-2",  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 19300
```

Data Setup in Wells:

```
1) Control  = 1, 16, 31, 46, 61, 76, 91 
2) LI 446-1 tube = 2, 17, 32, 47, 62, 77, 92
3) LI 446-1 10^7 = 3, 18, 33, 48, 63, 78, 93
4) LI 446-1 10^6 = 4, 19, 34, 49, 64, 79, 94
5) LI 446-1 10^5 = 5, 20, 35, 50, 65, 80, 95
6) Control = 6, 21, 36, 51, 66, 81, 96
7) LI-446-2 tube = 7, 22, 37, 52, 67, 82, 97
8) LI-446-2 10^7 = 8, 23, 38, 53, 68, 83, 98
9) LI-446-2 10^6 = 9, 24, 39, 54, 69, 84, 99
10) LI-446-2 10^5 = 10, 25, 40 ,55, 70, 85, 100
11) Control = 11, 26, 41, 56, 71, 86
12) LI-446-3 tube = 12, 27, 42, 57, 72, 87
13) LI-446-3 10^7 = 13, 28, 43, 58, 73, 88
14) LI-446-3 10^6 = 14, 29, 44, 59, 74, 89
15) LI-446-3 10^5 = 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90
```

I have 19300 columns of data, where 1:193 correspond to Well 1 at 15min intervals, 194:386 are Well 2 at 15 min intervals, etc up to Well 100.  However, 446-3 (AKA 11-15 above) are repeated 6 times and 446-1 and 446-2 are repeated 7 times.

`str(dm)
'data.frame':   19300 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Time..mins.: int  15 30 45 60 75 90 105 120 135 150 ...
 $ variable   : Factor w/ 100 levels "Well_1","Well_2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value      : num  0.439 0.204 0.191 0.187 0.185 0.19 0.187 0.19 0.188 0.191 ...
 $ Media      : Factor w/ 2 levels "BHI","BHI_salt": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Simulate one if you can't provide your own data in a manageable form, shape and size. Currently it's unclear what you're trying to repeat 7 or 6 times.

Comment: Can you paste the results from `str(dm)`?

Comment: Updated the data, let me know if I need to add more.  I don't do R studio often.